# how to generate a String random

Tags: java, android, random

I used an `EditText` widget where the client can enter information, then I saved several entries in an `ArrayList`. Now I want to randomly select one of these entries from the `ArrayList`. How can I select one element from an `ArrayList` at random?

I have already tried these ways but it crashes when I run it .

```
String myrandomString = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt(options.size()));

//int myrandomString = rand.nextInt(options.toString().length());
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your problem is from your question.  Please consider revising if you'd like a high quality / relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you already have an `ArrayList<String>` that contains previously entered strings and when a new string is entered by the user it is appended to this list.
What you would like to do is to select a random string from this list.
You can use the `java.util.Random` class to generate a random index from the list and return the word that is positioned on that index.
For example, the code bellow will print a random member of the test list on every execution.

```
Random random = new Random();

List<String> test = Arrays.asList("Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4");
System.out.println(test.get(Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % test.size()));
```

**EDIT**

As stated in the comments, replacing the `Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % test.size()` with `random.nextInt(test.size())` will make the code more readable and reduce the chances for generating a lot of duplicates (it will make the number distribution more uniform).

Comment: The method call [`random.nextInt(test.size())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) also accomplishes this without needing the final `% test.size()`

Comment: Not only does it accomplish the same, it's even much better. The modulo operation greatly reduces the randomness of the returned numbers.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar can you point me to some resources that explain why the modulo operator reduces the randomness in this case?

Comment: It's not only in this case, it's a general effect when using this kind of random number generator.  See Effective Java item 47 and e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27779177/effective-java-item-47-know-and-use-your-libraries-flawed-random-integer-meth

Comment: Thank you for the info guys I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Start by picking a random index within the arrayList size:

```
int randIdx = new Random().nextInt(arrayList.size());
```

Then get the String at that index

```
String randString = arrayList.get(randIdx);
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text, it makes for a better answer.